# Error: undeclared variable $

Tags: c, bison, yacc

When I run the `bison`program below (by `bison file.y`) , I get the error `missing a declaration type for $2 in 'seq'` :

```
%union {
       char cval;
}
%token <cval> AMINO 
%token STARTCODON STOPCODON

%%
series: STARTCODON seq STOPCODON {printf("%s", $2);}
seq : AMINO
         | seq AMINO
         ;
%%
```

I would like to know why I get this error, and how I can correctly declare the variable `$2`

Comment: Is it Bison that complains, or the C compiler when compiling the generated code? And please copy-paste the full and complete output of either Bison or the compiler into the question body.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I run the file by `bison file.y`, the error that I get (translated in English) is something like `is missing a declaration type for $2 in 'seq'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't told Bison what type `seq` is, so it doesn't know what to do with `$2`.

Use the `%type` directive:

```
%type <cval> seq
```

---

Note that the type used for `$2` is a single `char`, which is not a string as expected by the `"%s"` format. You need to come up with a way to create your own string from the sequence.

Comment: "to create your own string from the sequence" __and__ to assign it to `$$`.